# The multi-part identifier "t.PartNumber" could not be bound - with union

Tags: t-sql

I need the records from TableMain which have a record match in ActivePNs and also a match in [Parts]. It seems that a join should do the trick but I keep running up against either a "could not be bound" or a "invalid column name" error.

I'm sure I could accomplish what I need by creating a temp table, but I'm trying to keep it simple.

```
Select * from TableMain t
INNER JOIN  (select [PartNumber] 
    From ActivePNs ap
    Where ap.PartNumber = t.PartNumber
    Union
    select [Number] PartNumber 
    From [Parts] p
    Where p.Number = t.PartNumber) c 
On t.PartNumber = c.PartNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't multiple rows in ActivePNs or Parts for a given PartNumber, then from what I've understood, this should do the trick - only finding rows in TableMain that have a PartNumber in ActivePNs *and* Parts:

```
Select t.* 
from TableMain t
    INNER JOIN ActivePNs ap ON t.PartNumber = ap.PartNumber
    INNER JOIN Parts p ON t.PartNumber = p.Number
```

Comment: Sorry - I am looking for rows in TableMain that have a PartNumber in ActivePNs or Parts. Sigh - it also occurs to me that ActivePNs and Parts have some of the same records. So I would need to do a Group By as well it seems...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `SELECT` after the `UNION`.

```
select [Number] PartNumber   -- You rename Number to PartNumber
  From [Parts] p
  Where p.Number = t.PartNumber  -- but still reference Number here
```

The aliasing of `Number` in the `SELECT` means there's no column `p.Number` for use in the `WHERE` portion of the query.

Answer (score 0):

A derived table cannot be correlated with the tables it is being joined to. What you are trying to do could be implemented like this:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  COALESCE(ap.PartNumber, p.Number) AS PartNumber
FROM TableMain t
  LEFT JOIN ActivePN ap ON ap.PartNumber = t.PartNumber
  LEFT JOIN Parts p ON p.Number = t.PartNumber
WHERE NOT (ap.PartNumber IS NULL AND p.Number IS NULL)
```

Comment: Did you mean: WHERE NOT (ap.PartNumber IS NULL AND p.Number IS NULL)

Comment: @JonV: Basically, yes. I usually test PKs in such cases, but I should have clarified that right away, or used your version. Updated my answer.